# Words in English which elided medial 'g' or 'v' (or initial 'h' before 'l', 'n', or 'r')

Tags: english, sound-change, old-english

What I am looking for is a list of words which in Old English either had a medial 'v' sound (spelt 'f'), which was dropped in Modern English, so words like 'head' from 'heafod' and 'lord' from 'hlaford' (with the 'f' in both the examples being pronounced as we would pronounce 'v'), or a medial 'g' (pronounced as a voiced velar fricative since it appears between two vowels, as far as my knowledge goes, please do correct me if I am wrong) which was again dropped in Modern English, like archaic 'wain' from 'wægn' (I am not too sure about this one), or 'hail' from 'hagal'. I am also looking for words which elided initial 'h' before 'l' (like in 'hlaf' --> 'loaf') or 'r' ('hring' --> 'ring') or 'n' ('hnutu' --> 'nut'). If someone has an explanation to why they were dropped, I would also very much appreciate that as well. (I also have no idea what tags I should have put, since the question doesn't exactly fit in any of them)

Comment: Why they were dropped? Because they were weak sounds that easily get lost in rapid speech – same reason virtually all dropped sounds are dropped. Along with /h/, intervocalic velar fricatives or approximants like /ɣ/ and /ɰ/ are some of the most frequently lost sounds there are – apart from English they’ve been mostly or completely lost in French, Danish, Old/Middle Chinese, Irish, Turkish, Finnish, (Post-)Proto-Indo-European, West Greenlandic, and many, many more languages around the world.

Comment: Why can't you just open any Anglo-Saxon dictionary, look through the entries starting with _hl-, hn-, hr-_, and write out the ones that have Modern English counterparts? At my first glance I found _hlædel_ ‘laddle’, _hlǣder_ ‘ladder’, and _hlǣne_ ‘lean’. Here's a dictionary for you in case you don't have one: [_A Concise Anglo-Saxon Dictionary_](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m0sJHEMI82QeUQUX6B3EMqVTN6Cniqci/view?usp=sharing) (4th ed. 1960, reprinted 2000, 1st ed. 1894) by J.R. Clark Hall, with a supplement by Herbert D. Meritt.

Comment: Thank you very much for the dictionary, I was having trouble finding an easily searchable one.

Answer (score 9):

All the following information comes from Christopher Upward's [*The History of English Spelling*](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_History_of_English_Spelling.html?id=fNfebt79zdwC):

#### Words that lost initial ‘h’:

- OE *hlaf* ModE ‘loaf’
- OE *hlud* ModE ‘loud’
- OE *hlædder* ModE ‘ladder’
- OE *hlafdiȝe* ModE ‘lady’
- OE *hliehhan* ModE ‘to laugh’
- OE *hlid* ModE ‘lid’
- OE *hnecca* ModE ‘neck’
- OE *hnæȝan* mod ‘neigh’
- OE *hreddan* ModE ‘to rid’
- OE *hreoȝ* ModE ‘rough’
- OE *hrycȝ* ModE ‘ridge’
- OE *hræfen* ModE ‘raven’
- OE *hrinȝ* ModE ‘ring’
- OE *hrof* ModE ‘roof’

#### Words that lost medial [v]

- *hæfde* (‘had’)
- *heafoc* (‘hawk’)
- *heafod* (‘head’)
- *hlafdiȝe* (‘lady’)
- *hlaford* (‘lord’)
- *Ƿifman* (‘woman’)

#### Old English G that was pronounced [ɣ]

According to Christopher Upward, OE G was pronounced [ɣ] particularly between back vowels (p45). Upward says that this G has developed to W or I/Y depending on what precedes/follows the G:

- “OE G non-initially before and/or after A, O, U normally becomes ModE W”:

  - *aȝan* ‘owe’
  - *draȝan* ‘draw’
  - *ȝnaȝan* ‘gnaw’
  - *laȝu* ‘law’
  - *boȝa* ‘bow’
  - *ploȝ* ‘plow’
  - *fuȝel* ‘fowl’
  - *sorȝian* ‘to sorrow’
  - *mearȝ* ‘marrow’
- “After the front vowels Æ, E medial G typically fell silent or became incorporated into a vowel by the time of ModE, written AI”:

  - *fæȝer* ‘fair’
  - *hæȝel/ hæȝl* ‘hail’
  - *læȝde* ‘laid’
  - *leȝer* ‘lair’
  - *mæȝden* ‘maiden’
  - *næȝ(e)l* ‘nail’
  - *ræȝ(e)n* ‘rain’
  - *sæȝde* ‘said’
- “In final position this G led to ModE Y after OE front vowels”:

  - *cæȝ* ‘key’
  - *claȝ* ‘clay’
  - *dæȝ* ‘day’
  - *græȝ* ‘grey’
  - *Ƿeȝ* ‘way’
  - *driȝe* ‘dry’
  - *maniȝ* ‘many’

---

**Notes:**

- **OE** means Old English and **ModE** means Modern English
- ‘single quotation marks’ enclose Modern English words
- *italicised* words are Old English words
- “double quotation marks” have been used to enclose quotes (i.e. Upward's exact words)

Comment: The lists are far from being comprehensive, for example, the ones beginning with _hl-_ end at _hli-_, so further words are missing, like _hlot_ ‘lot’ or _hlūd_ ‘loud’. The same with _hn-_: _hnitu_ ‘nit’ and _hnutu_ ‘nut’ are missing.

Comment: BTW, the P-shaped letter in **Ƿeȝ** [was the OE letter for W](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/271259/106592)